# How do I create dynamic content looping through a nested JSON object?

Tags: json, reactjs

**React**

```
getSection (object) {

    let sectionContent = [],
        sectionContainers = [],
        i = 0;

    for(let sectionTitles in object){

        sectionContainers.push(<div className={"section " + sectionTitles}></div>);

        for(let sectionTitle in object[sectionTitles]) {

            sectionContainers.push(<div className={"section " + sectionTitle} key={sectionTitle + "-" + i.toString()}>{object[sectionTitles][sectionTitle]}</div>);
            i++;

        }
    }
```

**JSON**

```
 const sections = 
    {"resume": {
        "name": "[HEADLINE_TEXT]",
        "job-title": "[JOB_TITLE]",
        "timeframe": "[TIME_FRAME]",
        "company-name": "[COMPANY_NAME]",
        "job-description": "[JOB_DESCRIPTION]",
        "job-tech": "[JOB_TECH]"
    },
    "projects": {
        "name": "[HEADLINE_TEXT]",
        "job-title": "[JOB_TITLE]",
        "timeframe": "[TIME_FRAME]",
        "company-name": "[COMPANY_NAME]",
        "job-description": "[JOB_DESCRIPTION]",
        "job-tech": "[JOB_TECH]"
    }};
```

Trying to iterate through this JSON snippet, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, I know the first function `getSection()` has a closed `DIV` tag but that's because React crashes if I don't close the element. I'm coming from a little bit of a PHP background so I thought it worked the same, but clearly I was wrong. The goal is something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class=section__sectionTitle>
  <div class=section_element1></div>
  <div class=section__element2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why would you not use cosing tag?

Comment: Because in PHP you would iterate through the elements then wrap them a class DIV tag. That's what I'm referring to. something like this: `<div> <?php loop here ?> </div>`

Comment: i din't get your purpose, but you have to use closing tag.

Comment: You marked the question down, because you didn't get the question? Is that really a valid point for marking a question down? I clarified it here in the comments. The purpose is to iterate through a JSON object. I'm asking how do I do it with objects nested within objects.

Comment: nope, i din't find any issue.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I shouldn't have jumped to conclusions. Yeah I was trying to explain that I know it has to be closed, but I'm trying to figure it out and the easiest way for me to explain is by using a PHP example, since it's what I'm trying to do, is loop through a nested object

Comment: please relate your issue in the question that you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an array of HTML elements to `react`, for the code below, you can just create the nested object inside the render method. Here we iterate through the `JSON` using map and returning children

```
{Object.keys(sections).map((container, i) => {
   return (
    <div key={i}>
      {container}
       {Object.keys(sections[container]).map(content => {
         return <div> {sections[container][content]} </div>;
        })}
    </div>);
    })}
```

Here is a working example: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n45kjpz334)

Comment: This is close, I'm doing this with the for loops, my issue is that I'm trying to wrap the `<div className="sectionContainer"><div className="sectionContent"></div></div>` sorry if I'm not explaining this properly.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks bud! this is my final code: https://codesandbox.io/s/ko97n0mj87